# Objective-C categories: Can I add a property for a method not in my category?

Tags: objective-c, properties, categories

I want to use a category to make a method on the original class available as a property as well.

Class A:

```
@interface ClassA
- (NSString*)foo;
@end
```

Class A category

```
@interface ClassA (Properties)
- (void)someCategoryMethod;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *foo;
@end
```

Now when I do this, it seems to work (**EDIT:** Maybe it doesn't work, it doesn't complain but I am seeing strangeness), but it gives me warnings because I am not synthesizing the property in my category implementation.  How do I tell the compiler everything is actually just fine since the original class synthesizes the property for me?

Comment: Properties are (mostly) just sugar for a `-foo` and a `-setFoo` method. You can't add any extra instance variables in categories, but you can defined those methods. The @property syntax is optional, but suggested (I'm not sure if it works).

Comment: For anyone trying to add a property with a backing ivar (defined in the category as well), see this: http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/faking-ivars-in-objc-categories-with-associative-references/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C: Property in Category](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733104/objective-c-property-in-category)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's the warning you're getting:

`warning: property ‘foo’ requires method '-foo' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation`

To suppress this warning, have this in your implementation:

`@dynamic foo;`

Answer (score 1):

If something's declared in your category's interface, its definition belongs in your category's implementation.

Comment: But I don't have access to the source of `ClassA`.  Let's say it's class in UIKit that I am "improving".

Comment: You should probably be creating a subclass, not a category.

Comment: If it's a subclass, instances of this class created in areas I don't have control over will not have this code and properties.

Comment: You might look into method swizzling:
http://samsoff.es/posts/customize-uikit-with-method-swizzling
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637604/method-swizzle-on-iphone-device

Comment: find nice tutorial here http://www.techpaa.com/2012/04/adding-properties-to-categories-and.html

Comment: @JoshFreeman what about my answer above (or below) using Associated Objects? I think it's superior to method swizzling for both safety and neatness.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote two articles on this, though the concept is slightly different from the question you're asking.

1. Add properties to categories without touching the base class: http://compileyouidontevenknowyou.blogspot.com/2012/06/adding-properties-to-class-you-dont.html
2. Access iVars from categories: http://compileyouidontevenknowyou.blogspot.com/2012/06/if-you-want-to-keep-everything-in-your.html

This is a LOT better than method swizzling, at least: way safer.