# Since when is it possible to declare Objective-C 2.0 properties in a category?

Tags: objective-c, properties, categories

I always thought that one cannot declare an object property in a category.
Until my partner did it in our app's code, and it seemed to work.

I went on a SO and Google binge to try to explain to him that no, Objective-C categories can only be used to add methods, not properties.  I found questions such as:

- [Setting New Property In Category Interface Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098753/setting-new-properties-in-category-interface-implementation) (look at the accepted answer)
- [Can I add a property for a method not in my category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520889/objective-c-categories-can-i-add-a-property-for-a-method-not-in-my-category)

But then I found [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1) on Apple's site that contains the following about the @property declaration:

> A property declaration begins with the
>   keyword @property. @property can
>   appear anywhere in the method
>   declaration list found in the
>   @interface of a class. @property **can
>   also appear in the declaration of a
>   protocol or category**. (emphasis added)

I know that this doesn't work:

```
@interface MyClass ()
NSInteger foobar;
- (void) someCategorizedMethod;
@end
```

But this compiles:

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property NSInteger foobar;
- (void) someCategorizedMethod;
@end
```

My question is (a) what's the best practice here? and (b) is this something that is new to Objective-C 2.0, and instead of using a "real" iVar, it simply uses associative storage behind the scenes to make this work?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have always been able to declare an `@property` in a category.  What you couldn't do -- and still can't -- is declare storage for the property in the category, neither as an instance variable nor via `@synthesize.

However....

`@interface MyClass ()` is *not a category*.   It is a class extension and has a distinctly more specific role than a category.

Namely, a class extension can be used to *extend a class's @interface*, and this includes @properties that can be @synthesized (including synthesizing storage in the modern runtime).

```
Foo.h:

@interface Foo
@end

Foo.m:

@interface Foo()
@property int x;
@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize x; // synthesizes methods & storage
@end
```

> it simply uses associative storage
>   behind the scenes to make this work?

Nope -- it is a real instance variable.   The modern runtime fixes the fragile base class problem.

---

```
@interface MyClass ()
NSInteger foobar;
- (void) someCategorizedMethod;
@end
```

The above doesn't work (as expected) because `foobar` is, effectively, a global variable.

If you change it to:

```
@interface MyClass () {
    NSInteger foobar;
}
- (void) someCategorizedMethod;
@end
```

Then it'll work with the latest release of the llvm compiler (with the right flags, as @Joshua indicated in a comment).

Comment: To add to this, his first example where he adds an iVar is perfectly valid in llvm with -Xclang -fobjc-nonfragile-abi2

Comment: It would be if he were adding an ivar.  In that case, he is adding a static variable that is not an instance variable.

Comment: thank you for the extensive explanation.  I'll be sharing this link with my coding partners!!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, properties are nothing different from other methods. As long as the ivar used is available in the *ordinary* class, there is no problem at all. It's just syntactic sugar.

Things start to get more difficult if also the ivar is automatically created, as is possible in *some* configurations.

The main point here is that declaration of the ivar is independent from the property.

Answer (score 1):

Assotiative storage is the solution.
Have a look at this [post](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/faking-ivars-in-objc-categories-with-associative-references/).

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up -- this is indeed a possible way around this issue.