# Hiding properties from public framework headers, but leaving available internally

Tags: objective-c

I need to have property in class that is excluded from public framework headers, but it is available for use internally in other framework classes.
What I did right now is:

MyClass.h:

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject

@end
```

MyClass+Internal.h

```
@interface MyClass (Internal)
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *mySecretProperty;
@end
```

MyClass.m

```
#import "MyClass.h"
#import "MyClass+Internal.h"

@interface MyClass ()
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *mySecretProperty;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@end
```

And I can use private property like:

MyOtherClass.m:

```
#import "MyClass.h"
#import "MyClass+Internal.h"

@implementation MyOtherClass
- (void)test {
    MyClass *myClass = [MyClass new];
    NSLog(@"%@", myClass.mySecretProperty)
}
@end
```

But what I don't like about this setup is that I have duplicate declaration of property in my `Internal` Category and inside of anonymous Category. 
Is there a way to improve this setup?

Comment: As far as it is shared between classes, it isn't a secret property anymore, is it? I can't see any way to do it without duplication...

Comment: well, maybe I wasn't very clear. I want it to be visible in other framework class implementations, but not visible in any public header. (in this example `MyOtherClass` is another framework class)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you could do with the class extension only, there is no need to use a category. The quick fix would be to remove the category name from the parenthesis, transforming it into the class extension, then remove the class extension declaration from the .m file.
After this you only import the extension header in your framework classes and you make sure it is a private header of your framework.

**MyClass.h**

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject

@end
```

**MyClass+Internal.h**

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@interface MyClass ()
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *mySecretProperty;
@end
```

**MyClass.m**

```
#import "MyClass.h"
#import "MyClass+Internal.h"

@implementation MyClass
@end
```

**MyOtherClass.m:**

```
#import "MyClass.h"
#import "MyClass+Internal.h"

@implementation MyOtherClass
- (void)test {
    MyClass *myClass = [MyClass new];
    NSLog(@"%@", myClass.mySecretProperty)
}
@end
```

The key is understanding the difference between categories and class extensions, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4540582/703809

Comment: If MyClass+Internal.h imports MyClass.h, do you still need to import both in MyClass.m? Couldn't you only import MyClass+Internal.h?

Comment: @AdamJohns No you don't actually need both in MyClass.m, but it also doesn't cost anything to have them. I always used to keep all the separate imports in my .m file for better readability.