# Objective c: giving secret APIs which will not visible in header

Tags: objective-c, oop, design-patterns

I want to wrap an object in Objective c, so that user can't initialise or change any parameter.

For example,

I am building restaurantManager module. So after initialisation user will call `[restaurantManagerObject searchforAvailableDrink]` which is a async call. It will invoke restaurantManager delegate `didDrinkAvailable:(Drink*)drink`.

I will create drink from lower layer and send it to the delegate. To do that **I need to initialise Drink object and set the desired attributes to drink from another internal class**.

But I don't want to make those APIs visible to the header. User will only get a ready made drink object where he can use some attributes and public methods.

How to do that ?

Comment: You could have two header files. One public, one private.

Comment: @Thilo, Could you please give me an example, how to make two headers for single class ?

Comment: Maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/647104/14955  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095716/hiding-properties-from-public-framework-headers-but-leaving-available-internall

Comment: Perhaps take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/651422/115865