# Objective-C: Property / instance variable in category

Tags: objective-c, categories

As I cannot create a synthesized property in a Category in Objective-C, I do not know how to optimize the following code:

```
@interface MyClass (Variant)
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *test;
@end

@implementation MyClass (Variant)

@dynamic test;

- (NSString *)test {
    NSString *res;
    //do a lot of stuff
    return res;
}

@end
```

The *test-method* is called multiple times on runtime and I'm doing a lot of stuff to calculate the result. Normally using a synthesized property I store the value in a IVar _test the first time the method is called, and just returning this IVar next time. How can I optimized the above code?

Comment: Why not do what you normally do, only instead of a category, add the property to a MyClass base class?  And to take it further, perform your heavy stuff on the background and have the process fire off a notification or call some handler for MyClass when the process is complete.

Comment: MyClass is a generated class from Core Data. If I but my custom object code inside the generated class it would disappear if I regenerate the class from my Core Data. Because of this, I'm using a category.

Comment: Maybe accept the question which applies best to the title? ("Property in category")

Comment: Why not just create a subclass?

Comment: Even the pseudo code in your question is misleading. A category is NOT a (Variant). It is an ADDITION to the functionality of the class. It CAN override existing methods, but that's an edge case with many nor-very-expected-behaviors.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

@lorean's method will work <sup><sub>(note: answer is now deleted)</sub></sup>, but you'd only have a single storage slot.  So if you wanted to use this on multiple instances and have each instance compute a distinct value, it wouldn't work.

Fortunately, the Objective-C runtime has this thing called [Associated Objects](http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/) that can do exactly what you're wanting:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static void *MyClassResultKey;
@implementation MyClass

- (NSString *)test {
  NSString *result = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &MyClassResultKey);
  if (result == nil) {
    // do a lot of stuff
    result = ...;
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &MyClassResultKey, result, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
  }
  return result;
}

@end
```

Comment: fixed link for Associated Objects: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH24-SW1

Comment: Great answer! You can even get rid the static variable using `@selector(test)` as a key, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020918/avoid-extra-static-variables-for-associated-objects-keys/16020927#16020927

Comment: Answer is good, but does not answer how to make the proeprty :) Just how to store values.

Comment: @DaveDeLong - How can I do the same using NSInteger or float?

Comment: Don't use this if you ever plan on using Swift, because it won't work for Swift. So if you need to use that property in Swift you'll hit a wall.

Comment: @HotFudgeSunday - think it does work in swift: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133058/is-there-a-way-to-set-associated-objects-in-swift

Comment: @DaveDeLong Why not just create a subclass?

Comment: @ScottZhu for many reasons, sometimes you can't subclass. Maybe the objects are created for you. Maybe it's a class cluster. Etc

Answer (score 178):

**.h-file**

```
@interface NSObject (LaserUnicorn)

@property (nonatomic, strong) LaserUnicorn *laserUnicorn;

@end
```

**.m-file**

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static void * LaserUnicornPropertyKey = &LaserUnicornPropertyKey;

@implementation NSObject (LaserUnicorn)

- (LaserUnicorn *)laserUnicorn {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, LaserUnicornPropertyKey);
}

- (void)setLaserUnicorn:(LaserUnicorn *)unicorn {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, LaserUnicornPropertyKey, unicorn, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC); 
}

@end
```

**Just like a normal property - accessible with dot-notation**

```
NSObject *myObject = [NSObject new];
myObject.laserUnicorn = [LaserUnicorn new];
NSLog(@"Laser unicorn: %@", myObject.laserUnicorn);
```

---

**Easier syntax**

Alternatively you could use `@selector(nameOfGetter)` instead of creating a static pointer key like so:

```
- (LaserUnicorn *)laserUnicorn {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(laserUnicorn));
}

- (void)setLaserUnicorn:(LaserUnicorn *)unicorn {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(laserUnicorn), unicorn, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC); 
}
```

For more details see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16020927/202451

Comment: Good article.  One thing to note is an update in the article. __Update December 22, 2011: It’s important to note that the key for the association is a void pointer void *key, not a string. That means that when retrieving an associated reference, you have to pass the exact same pointer to the runtime. It would not work as intended if you used a C string as the key, then copied the string to another place in memory and tried to access the associated reference by passing the pointer to the copied string as a key.__

Comment: You really don't need the `@dynamic objectTag;`. `@dynamic` means the setter & getter will be generated somewhere else, but in this case they're implemented right here.

Comment: @NSAddict true! Fixed!

Comment: How about the dealloc of laserUnicorns for manual memory management? Is this a memory leak?

Comment: Is released automatically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039309/when-does-an-associated-object-get-released

Comment: What is the meaning of declaring the property as 'retain'? There is no real instance variable that can be retained.

Comment: @kernix Well, telling every user of the class wether the object is retained, assigned or copied can be usefull/important information.

Comment: @hfossli so this is only used for documentation purposes to reflect the use of OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC under the hood(as there is no actual instance variable).

Comment: @kernix Correct. Just to be clear about how the memory management is for that object.

Comment: Hey, there is a serious issue with this sample: ``static void * LaserUnicornsPropertyKey`` defaults to ``0``, so we are passing ``0`` to  objc_setAssociatedObject instead of a unique pointer which is problematic when associating multiple properties this way. Use ``&LaserUnicornsPropertyKey``! (Wanted to edit the post to fix this but my edit got rejected, can someone fix this?)

Comment: great answer! however don't forget to `#import <objc/runtime.h>`in category .m file otherwise. compile time error: _Implicit declaration of function 'objc_getAssociatedObject' is invalid in C99_  comes up. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408934/implicit-declaration-of-function-objc-getassociatedobject-is-invalid-in-c99

Answer (score 34):

The given answer works great and my proposal is just an extension to it that avoids writing too much boilerplate code.

In order to avoid writing repeatedly getter and setter methods for category properties this answer introduces macros. Additionally these macros ease the use of primitive type properties such as `int` or `BOOL`.

**Traditional approach without macros**

Traditionally you define a category property like

```
@interface MyClass (Category)
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *text;
@end
```

Then you need to implement a getter and setter method using an *associated object* and the *get selector* as the key ([see original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733104/objective-c-property-instance-variable-in-category/#8733320)):

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation MyClass (Category)
- (NSString *)text{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(text));
}

- (void)setText:(NSString *)text{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(text), text, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
@end
```

**My suggested approach**

Now, using a macro you will write instead:

```
@implementation MyClass (Category)

CATEGORY_PROPERTY_GET_SET(NSString*, text, setText:)

@end
```

The macros are defined as following:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

#define CATEGORY_PROPERTY_GET(type, property) - (type) property { return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(property)); }
#define CATEGORY_PROPERTY_SET(type, property, setter) - (void) setter (type) property { objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(property), property, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC); }
#define CATEGORY_PROPERTY_GET_SET(type, property, setter) CATEGORY_PROPERTY_GET(type, property) CATEGORY_PROPERTY_SET(type, property, setter)

#define CATEGORY_PROPERTY_GET_NSNUMBER_PRIMITIVE(type, property, valueSelector) - (type) property { return [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(property)) valueSelector]; }
#define CATEGORY_PROPERTY_SET_NSNUMBER_PRIMITIVE(type, property, setter, numberSelector) - (void) setter (type) property { objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(property), [NSNumber numberSelector: property], OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC); }

#define CATEGORY_PROPERTY_GET_UINT(property) CATEGORY_PROPERTY_GET_NSNUMBER_PRIMITIVE(unsigned int, property, unsignedIntValue)
#define CATEGORY_PROPERTY_SET_UINT(property, setter) CATEGORY_PROPERTY_SET_NSNUMBER_PRIMITIVE(unsigned int, property, setter, numberWithUnsignedInt)
#define CATEGORY_PROPERTY_GET_SET_UINT(property, setter) CATEGORY_PROPERTY_GET_UINT(property) CATEGORY_PROPERTY_SET_UINT(property, setter)
```

The macro `CATEGORY_PROPERTY_GET_SET` adds a getter and setter for the given property. Read-only or write-only properties will use the `CATEGORY_PROPERTY_GET` and `CATEGORY_PROPERTY_SET` macro respectively.

**Primitive types need a little more attention**

As primitive types are no objects the above macros contain an example for using `unsigned int` as the property's type. It does so by wrapping the integer value into a `NSNumber` object. So its usage is analog to the previous example:

```
@interface ...
@property unsigned int value;
@end

@implementation ...
CATEGORY_PROPERTY_GET_SET_UINT(value, setValue:)
@end
```

Following this pattern, you can simply add more macros to also support `signed int`, `BOOL`, etc...

**Limitations**

1. All macros are using `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC` by default.
2. IDEs like *App Code* do currently not recognize the setter's name when refactoring the property's name. You would need to rename it by yourself.

Comment: don't forget to `#import <objc/runtime.h>`in category .m file otherwise. compile time error: _Implicit declaration of function 'objc_getAssociatedObject' is invalid in C99_  comes up. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408934/implicit-declaration-of-function-objc-getassociatedobject-is-invalid-in-c99

Answer (score 8):

Just use [libextobjc](https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc) library:

h-file:

```
@interface MyClass (Variant)
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *test;
@end
```

m-file:

```
#import <extobjc.h>
@implementation MyClass (Variant)

@synthesizeAssociation (MyClass, test);

@end
```

[More about @synthesizeAssociation](https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc/blob/master/extobjc/EXTSynthesize.h)

Comment: What is the correct way to override an accessor with this (e.g. lazy load a property)

Answer (score 3):

Tested only with iOS 9
Example: Adding an UIView property to UINavigationBar (Category)

UINavigationBar+Helper.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UINavigationBar (Helper)
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *tkLogoView;
@end
```

UINavigationBar+Helper.m

```
#import "UINavigationBar+Helper.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

#define kTKLogoViewKey @"tkLogoView"

@implementation UINavigationBar (Helper)

- (void)setTkLogoView:(UIView *)tkLogoView {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, kTKLogoViewKey, tkLogoView, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (UIView *)tkLogoView {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, kTKLogoViewKey);
}

@end
```

Answer (score -2):

Another possible solution, perhaps easier, which doesn't use `Associated Objects` is to declare a variable in the category implementation file as follows:

```
@interface UIAlertView (UIAlertViewAdditions)

- (void)setObject:(id)anObject;
- (id)object;

@end


@implementation UIAlertView (UIAlertViewAdditions)

id _object = nil;

- (id)object
{
    return _object;
}

- (void)setObject:(id)anObject
{
    _object = anObject;
}
@end
```

The downside of this sort of implementation is that the object doesn't function as an instance variable, but rather as a class variable. Also, property attributes can't be assigned(such as used in Associated Objects like OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)

Comment: The question asks about instance variable. Your solution is just like Lorean

Comment: Really?? Did you know what you're doing? You created a pair of getter/setter method to access an internal variable which is independent for a file BUT a class object, that is, if you allocate two UIAlertView class objects, the object values of their are the same!