# Implicit declaration of function objc_getAssociatedObject is invalid in C99

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to use Associated Objects on my objective-c category and I'm getting this warning.

```
Implicit declaration of function 'objc_getAssociatedObject' is invalid in C99
```

Also I'm using arc if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

have you added

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

at the beginning of your file?

Comment: Thanks for your answer it solved my problem, but what is this library for?

Comment: @antf - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

I copied those line before draw function
its working now

```
GL_API void GL_APIENTRY glEnableClientState (GLenum array);

GL_API void GL_APIENTRY glDisableClientState (GLenum array);

GL_API void GL_APIENTRY glVertexPointer (GLint size, GLenum type, GLsizei stride, const GLvoid *pointer);

GL_API void GL_APIENTRY glColor4f (GLfloat red, GLfloat green, GLfloat blue, GLfloat alpha);
```