# Objective-C Categories and Properties

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

In Objective-C I can create categories to extend a class. I can also add properties to them as they are basically only methods. However I cannot bind them with @synthesize or any other way I know. Therefore whenever I try to use them the app would crash.

Is there any use of properties in categories or are they just possible because it would break the logic of the language to forbid them. Could you give me a scenario where defining a property in a category would make sense?

Comment: See my answer to your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502539/objective-c-category-and-new-ivar (Why did you ask the essentially the same question twice?)

Comment: Thank you. I thought that besides a solution to my concrete problem it might als be interesting to have a more general question on what properties in categories are good for. However your answer seems to provide both already. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C: Property in Category](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733104/objective-c-property-in-category)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main use of defining property in category is in creating class extension, with the help of category when we create class extension then there we can define property and synthesise them as well.This is the way to achieve hiding of property for public access.

You can check this for more information - http://www.techpaa.com/2012/04/adding-properties-to-categories-and.html

Comment: Category is NOT an extension : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html

Comment: removed downvote as your answer does solve the problem but I still stand for Categories not supporting properties

Comment: Associated Objects != Properties

Comment: correct, both are not the same. But we can use property in this way if there is a need.

Answer (score 0):

From [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html) guide

> A category allows you to add methods to an existing class—even to one
>   for which you do not have the source. Categories are a powerful
>   feature that allows you to extend the functionality of existing
>   classes without subclassing.

Since you want to

> add properties to them as they are basically only methods

You can use the category to add methods to the class.

Comment: and what about category used for Class extensions.

Comment: @rishi The documentation says "Class extensions are similar".  That implies Class extensions and categories are 2 different things

Comment: class extensions and categories are indeed very different. In an extension I can define a property but and synthesize it. In a category I cannot synthesize the properties. But I can also not create ivars so that I cannot really implement the getters and setters for myself either.

Comment: Also yes I can add properties, but what are they good for if I can not bind them to any variable?

Comment: I wouldn't add properties to a category implementation. The docs state categories are for adding methods. Why bend the language to do what you have in mind? Subclassing is a good fit for adding ivars and methods to an existing class.

Comment: @Maudicus that is basically what I wanted to know. I do not necessarily want to add properties to a category. I just wondered why it is possible, because it does not seem to fit Apples intentions of what categories should be used for...

Comment: @Maudicus - sometimes that help us a lot, check out this blog to understand its power - http://rafaelsteil.com/2011/07/15/a-useful-uiview-addition-via-categories-objective-c-ios/

Comment: @rishi I understand that usage case, but in reality the blog is still creating methods to gain access to the fields of CGRect.  The use of properties on that blog only creates "shorthand notation" to those methods. I am an advocate of using brackets to call messages in general.