# Overriding property setter in a class category

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've got an `NSManagedObject` class that I want to override a setter to but I've been told it's good practice to not modify the automatically generated class file and create categories to instead extend them (because if you change the model and regenerate the file, you lose all your additions).

If I make a method for the setter in a category, it definitely runs the method (tested with NSLog), but I don't know how to assign the actual property value. Normally, I'd synthesise the property using

`@synthesize finished = _finished;`

so that I can access the property in the setter using `_finished`, like so:

```
- (void)setFinished:(NSNumber *)finishedValue {
    _finished = finishedValue;
    self.end_time = [NSDate date];
}
```

but where the property is defined in the `NSManagedObject` this doesn't seem possible.

Comment: You get an error saying you cannot synthesize in a category

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but gets you to where you're going in a different way: http://compileyouidontevenknowyou.blogspot.com/2012/06/adding-properties-to-class-you-dont.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do with subclassing see the doc [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW14)

```
- (void)setName:(NSString *)newName
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"name"];
    [self setPrimitiveName:newName];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"name"];
}
```

Comment: Using `[self setPrimitiveValue:finished forKey:@"finished"]` appears to work in the category, that's what I was looking for, thanks for leading me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

In a category, you can't add property value, only methods. So you will need to subClass in order to perform what you want.

Comment: you can, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733104/objective-c-property-instance-variable-in-category

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to do so, try the following:

Model.h

```
@interface Model
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString  * string;
@end
```

Model + Override.m

```
@interface Model ()
{
    NSString *_string;
} 
@end

@implementation Model (Override) 
- (void)setString:(NSString *)string
{
    return _string = string;
}    
@end
```