# Obj C: Can't inherit public property from parent class in child class

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, inheritance, parent-child

I am practicing inheritance in Objective-C and this is my Person parent class

```
// This is Person.h
@interface Person : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *age;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *race;

-(instancetype)init;
-(instancetype)initWithAge:(NSNumber*)age andRace:(NSString*)race;

@end
```

This is what I'm trying to do in my Student class

```
// This is Student.h
#import "Person.h"

@interface Student : Person

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *classification;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *major;

@end
```

And

```
// This is Student.m
#import "Student.h"
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Student

-(instancetype)init
{   
    return [self initWithClassification:@"Freshman" andMajor:@"Computer Science"
                                 andAge:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:20] andRace:@"Caucasian"];
}

-(instancetype)initWithClassification:(NSString*)classification andMajor:(NSString*)major
                               andAge:(NSNumber*)age andRace:(NSString*)race
{
    self = [super init];

if (self)
{
    _classification = classification;
    _major = major;
    _age = age;
    _race = race;
}

return self;
}

@end
```

The compiler is not liking my doing
    _age = age;
    _race = race;

Use of undeclared identifier _age did you mean age? Can someone tell me where I went wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Subclasses should avoid initializing inherited instance variables. That should be left up to the superclass initialization code, which is why your initializer methods should always call `[super init...]`.

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a property like that, clang will automatically `@synthesize` it for you (i.e it will create a getter and setter), but synthesized properties are not visible to subclasses, you have different alternatives to make it working.

You can synthesize the ivar in the interface of the subclass

```
@synthesize age = _age;
```

Or you can declare the ivar protected on the interface of the superclass, so that will be visible on the subclasses.

```
@interface Person : NSObject {
    @protected NSNumber *_age;
}
```

Or you can use `self.age = ...` on your subclass, without using the ivar at all.

Answer (score 1):

Since clang compiler now auto-synthesise properties you don't have, in most cases, to synthesise your properties.

> Objective-C Autosynthesis of Properties
>
> Clang provides support for autosynthesis of declared properties. Using
>   this feature, clang provides default synthesis of those properties not
>   declared @dynamic and not having user provided backing getter and
>   setter methods. __has_feature(objc_default_synthesize_properties)
>   checks for availability of this feature in version of clang being
>   used.

But in some cases (some examples are in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784454/when-should-i-use-synthesize-explicitly)) you should explicitly synthesise them.

In this case, to solve your problems you should just add:

```
@synthesize age = _age;
@synthesize race = _race;
```

to your code, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The subclass has access to the property, but not the backing variable.  So you should set it with

```
self.age = age;
```