# When to synthesize objective

Tags: objective-c

I am having some difficulty understanding what objects are supposed to be synthesized. For example:

```
@interface DoSomething : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor *frameColor;
@property BOOL toggleScrollability;
- (void) changeBackgroundColorOfView;

@end
```

In the `.m` file, which of these three items should be synthesized? Is there any disadvantage if I try and synthesize them all? In general, what is the rule of thumb for what objects you are supposed to synthesize?

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_property_accessor_synthesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two are properties; the third is an instance method. `@synthesize` applies only to properties.

However, if you're building for iOS 6 or newer, you don't need to synthesize at all. The compiler has handled this automatically for the last few years now.

Comment: So the autocompiler treats it as `@synthesize frameColor = _frameColor` ?

Comment: "You don't need to synthesize at all" ... Note, there are still situations where you must `@synthesize`. See the accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784454/when-should-i-use-synthesize-explicitly for a clear articulation of these situations. But you're right that, in the vast majority of cases, we don't manually synthesize any more.

Answer (score 0):

You can only synthesize properties, so you won't be able to write `@synthesize changeBackgroundColorOfView`.

Since XCode 4 I think, you don't have to use @synthesize anymore. The compiler automatically add it when it needs to be and you can access it by adding a _ before the name of your property.

In your example, you will access the frameColor property as `_frameColor` if you are in the DoSomething class, `doSomethingInstance.frameColor` if not.

But, you can always add it yourself if you want to rename your property for internal stuff.

See [Apple's reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/programmingwithobjectivec/encapsulatingdata/encapsulatingdata.html).