# After updating to Xcode 6 many incompatible conversion assignment warnings / errors appeared

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, xcode6

After updating to Xcode 6 many incompatible conversion assignment warnings / errors started to appeared

In the .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL *done;
```

In the .m file:

```
@synthesize done;
- (id)init
{
if (self = [super init])
{
    self.done = FALSE;
}
return self;
}

- (void) crashed {
    self.done = TRUE;  #this line gives an incompatible type conversion warning
}
```

Lots of these warnings appeared after the upgrade. Does anyone share similar problem?
This is not a localized problem, the issue spread across the entire project.
I thought some of my foundation was wrong, or is it ?

Comment: This is GOOD because you can learn when to _not_ using pointer

Comment: Also `YES` and `NO`, not `TRUE` and `FALSE`. If you are writing Objective-C use the Objective-C conventions. Also @synthesize is no longer necessary.

Comment: It appears you need a modern tutorial. The one you are following is out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all variables in Objective C have to be declared with the `*` character as some newcomers to the language think. It is C legacy to show that the variable is a pointer to an object. Some basic types like `int` and `BOOL` are too simple to require the overhead of storing them in an object, so C-style primitive types are used. From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html):

> Scalar types are used in situations where you just don’t need the
>   benefits (or associated         overheads) of using an object to
>   represent a value. While strings of characters are usually represented
>   as instances of the NSString class, numeric values are often stored in
>   scalar local variables or properties.

BOOL is a [primitive data type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type) in Objective C and is not supposed to be a pointer. The warnings are correct. Declare the variable like this:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL done;
```

Note the lack of the `*` character next to the variable name. Other primitive types like `int` or `float` also should be declared in a similar fashion.

Some other things about your code. The correct Objective C convention for BOOL values is `YES` instead of `TRUE` and `NO` instead of `FALSE`, so you should stick to it. Also, since Xcode 4.4, you don't need `@synthesize` outside of a few special cases [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784454/when-should-i-use-synthesize-explicitly). As pointed out in the comments, it's also better to use `instancetype` instead of `id` in your case as described in [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you want to do it this way:

#### Header file

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL done;  // Note: NOT a pointer
```

#### Implementation file

```
- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.done = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)crashed {
    self.done = YES;
}
```

Comment: Also, Apple recommend `instancetype` instead of `id` as the return type of methods that return an instance of the class they are called on. Doc link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html