# errors when building electron from source with gn and ninja on Mac OS 10.15

Tags: macos, electron, ninja

at the moment, I try to fix some accessibility bugs in electron. For that, I had tried to build electron from source. The source isn't edited or changed from me, so it is original.

I pulled the source from the official repo on GitHub, following the building instructions and I had used the client and so on.

Here is the output of my steps in the terminal under Mac OS X 10.15:

```
Christophers-MacBook-Pro:src chpross$ gn gen out/Testing --args="import(\"//electron/build/args/testing.gn\") $GN_EXTRA_ARGS"
Done. Made 11597 targets from 1978 files in 6073ms

Christophers-MacBook-Pro:src chpross$ ninja -C out/Testing electron
ninja: Entering directory `out/Testing'
[8992/26566] CXX obj/services/network/..._cpp_sources/udp_socket.mojom-shared.o^[9026/26566] CXX obj/services/network/...content_security_policy.mojom-shared.o^[9044/26566] CXX obj/services/video_ca...ed_cpp_sources/receiver.mojom-shared.o^[9047/26566] CXX obj/services/video_ca...ared_cpp_sources/device.mojom-shared.o^[9098/26566] CXX obj/v8/torque_generat...itializers/object-fromentries-tq-csa.o^[9160/26566] CXX obj/third_party/blink...nderer/core/inspector/generated/Page.o^[10130/26566] OBJCXX obj/components/vi...tal_context_provider/metal_api_proxy.o
FAILED: obj/components/viz/common/metal_context_provider/metal_api_proxy.o 
/Users/chpross/programmierung/electron-gn/src/electron/external_binaries/sccache ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++ -MMD -MF obj/components/viz/common/metal_context_provider/metal_api_proxy.o.d -DVIZ_METAL_CONTEXT_PROVIDER_IMPLEMENTATION -DDCHECK_ALWAYS_ON=1 -D_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_ALIGNED_ALLOCATION -DCR_XCODE_VERSION=1120 -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=\"373424-64a362e7-1\" -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_LIBCPP_ABI_UNSTABLE -D_LIBCPP_DISABLE_VISIBILITY_ANNOTATIONS -D_LIBCXXABI_DISABLE_VISIBILITY_ANNOTATIONS -D_LIBCPP_ENABLE_NODISCARD -DCR_LIBCXX_REVISION=361348 -D__ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES=0 -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=0 -DWEBP_EXTERN=extern -DENABLE_IPC_FUZZER -DUSE_EGL -DSK_GL -DSK_HAS_PNG_LIBRARY -DSK_HAS_WEBP_LIBRARY -DSK_USER_CONFIG_HEADER=\"../../skia/config/SkUserConfig.h\" -DSK_HAS_JPEG_LIBRARY -DSK_SUPPORT_GPU=1 -DSK_GPU_WORKAROUNDS_HEADER=\"gpu/config/gpu_driver_bug_workaround_autogen.h\" -DSK_BUILD_FOR_MAC -DSK_METAL -DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=0 -DU_ENABLE_DYLOAD=0 -DUSE_CHROMIUM_ICU=1 -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DICU_UTIL_DATA_IMPL=ICU_UTIL_DATA_FILE -DUCHAR_TYPE=uint16_t -I../.. -Igen -I../../third_party/libwebp/src -I../../third_party/skia -I../../third_party/boringssl/src/include -I../../third_party/icu/source/common -I../../third_party/icu/source/i18n -I../../third_party/khronos -I../../gpu -I../../third_party/mesa_headers -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -fcolor-diagnostics -fmerge-all-constants -fcrash-diagnostics-dir=../../tools/clang/crashreports -Xclang -mllvm -Xclang -instcombine-lower-dbg-declare=0 -fcomplete-member-pointers -arch x86_64 -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__= -D__TIME__= -D__TIMESTAMP__= -Xclang -fdebug-compilation-dir -Xclang . -no-canonical-prefixes -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wthread-safety -Wextra-semi -Wunguarded-availability -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-c++11-narrowing -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-undefined-var-template -Wno-ignored-pragma-optimize -Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-c99-designator -Wno-final-dtor-non-final-class -Wno-sizeof-array-div -O2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -gdwarf-4 -g1 -isysroot ../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.10.0 -fvisibility=hidden -Xclang -add-plugin -Xclang find-bad-constructs -Wheader-hygiene -Wstring-conversion -Wtautological-overlap-compare -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-call-cxx-cdtors -Wobjc-missing-property-synthesis -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -include obj/components/viz/common/metal_context_provider/precompile.h-mm -c ../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm -o obj/components/viz/common/metal_context_provider/metal_api_proxy.o
../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm:224:17: error: auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'hasUnifiedMemory' declared in protocol 'MTLDevice' [-Werror,-Wobjc-protocol-property-synthesis]
@implementation MTLDeviceProxy
                ^
../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Headers/MTLDevice.h:353:27: note: property declared here
@property (readonly) BOOL hasUnifiedMemory API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.15), ios(13.0));
                          ^
../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm:578:1: note: add a '@synthesize' directive
@end
^
../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm:224:17: error: auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'location' declared in protocol 'MTLDevice' [-Werror,-Wobjc-protocol-property-synthesis]
@implementation MTLDeviceProxy
                ^
../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Headers/MTLDevice.h:368:40: note: property declared here
@property (readonly) MTLDeviceLocation location API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.15)) API_UNAVAILABLE(ios);
                                       ^
../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm:578:1: note: add a '@synthesize' directive
@end
^
../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm:224:17: error: auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'locationNumber' declared in protocol 'MTLDevice' [-Werror,-Wobjc-protocol-property-synthesis]
@implementation MTLDeviceProxy
                ^
../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Headers/MTLDevice.h:377:33: note: property declared here
@property (readonly) NSUInteger locationNumber API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.15)) API_UNAVAILABLE(ios);
                                ^
../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm:578:1: note: add a '@synthesize' directive
@end
^
../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm:224:17: error: auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'maxTransferRate' declared in protocol 'MTLDevice' [-Werror,-Wobjc-protocol-property-synthesis]
@implementation MTLDeviceProxy
                ^
../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Headers/MTLDevice.h:385:31: note: property declared here
@property (readonly) uint64_t maxTransferRate API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.15)) API_UNAVAILABLE(ios);
                              ^
../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm:578:1: note: add a '@synthesize' directive
@end
^
../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm:224:17: error: auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'barycentricCoordsSupported' declared in protocol 'MTLDevice' [-Werror,-Wobjc-protocol-property-synthesis]
@implementation MTLDeviceProxy
                ^
../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Headers/MTLDevice.h:421:64: note: property declared here
@property(readonly, getter=areBarycentricCoordsSupported) BOOL barycentricCoordsSupported API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.15)) API_UNAVAILABLE(ios);
                                                               ^
../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm:578:1: note: add a '@synthesize' directive
@end
^
../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm:224:17: error: auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'supportsShaderBarycentricCoordinates' declared in protocol 'MTLDevice' [-Werror,-Wobjc-protocol-property-synthesis]
@implementation MTLDeviceProxy
                ^
../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Headers/MTLDevice.h:423:27: note: property declared here
@property (readonly) BOOL supportsShaderBarycentricCoordinates API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.15)) API_UNAVAILABLE(ios);
                          ^
../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm:578:1: note: add a '@synthesize' directive
@end
^
../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm:224:17: error: auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'peerGroupID' declared in protocol 'MTLDevice' [-Werror,-Wobjc-protocol-property-synthesis]
@implementation MTLDeviceProxy
                ^
../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Headers/MTLDevice.h:753:31: note: property declared here
@property (readonly) uint64_t peerGroupID API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.15)) API_UNAVAILABLE(ios);
                              ^
../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm:578:1: note: add a '@synthesize' directive
@end
^
../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm:224:17: error: auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'peerIndex' declared in protocol 'MTLDevice' [-Werror,-Wobjc-protocol-property-synthesis]
@implementation MTLDeviceProxy
                ^
../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Headers/MTLDevice.h:760:31: note: property declared here
@property (readonly) uint32_t peerIndex API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.15)) API_UNAVAILABLE(ios);
                              ^
../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm:578:1: note: add a '@synthesize' directive
@end
^
../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm:224:17: error: auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'peerCount' declared in protocol 'MTLDevice' [-Werror,-Wobjc-protocol-property-synthesis]
@implementation MTLDeviceProxy
                ^
../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Headers/MTLDevice.h:766:31: note: property declared here
@property (readonly) uint32_t peerCount API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.15)) API_UNAVAILABLE(ios);
                              ^
../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm:578:1: note: add a '@synthesize' directive
@end
^
../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm:224:17: error: auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'counterSets' declared in protocol 'MTLDevice' [-Werror,-Wobjc-protocol-property-synthesis]
@implementation MTLDeviceProxy
                ^
../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Headers/MTLDevice.h:782:60: note: property declared here
@property (readonly, nullable) NSArray<id<MTLCounterSet>>* counterSets API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.15)) API_UNAVAILABLE(ios);
                                                           ^
../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm:578:1: note: add a '@synthesize' directive
@end
^
../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm:224:17: error: method 'supportsFamily:' in protocol 'MTLDevice' not implemented [-Werror,-Wprotocol]
@implementation MTLDeviceProxy
                ^
../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Headers/MTLDevice.h:659:1: note: method 'supportsFamily:' declared here
- (BOOL)supportsFamily:(MTLGPUFamily)gpuFamily API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.15), ios(13.0));
^
../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm:224:17: error: method 'newCounterSampleBufferWithDescriptor:error:' in protocol 'MTLDevice' not implemented [-Werror,-Wprotocol]
@implementation MTLDeviceProxy
                ^
../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Headers/MTLDevice.h:793:1: note: method 'newCounterSampleBufferWithDescriptor:error:' declared here
- (nullable id<MTLCounterSampleBuffer>) newCounterSampleBufferWithDescriptor:(MTLCounterSampleBufferDescriptor*)descriptor
^
../../components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm:224:17: error: method 'sampleTimestamps:gpuTimestamp:' in protocol 'MTLDevice' not implemented [-Werror,-Wprotocol]
@implementation MTLDeviceProxy
                ^
../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Headers/MTLDevice.h:803:1: note: method 'sampleTimestamps:gpuTimestamp:' declared here
-(void)sampleTimestamps:(NSUInteger *)cpuTimestamp
^
13 errors generated.
[10139/26566] CXX obj/v8/v8_initializers/code-stub-assembler.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

So different ninja targets produces different errors. I thing this is to big for one question, so if someone need this errors, I can paste it in a pastebin. The source code is official, but the build failed, I had already restarted the system, cleaned the out-dir and so on. Hopefully someone know what's went wrong here.

Comment: Quick checking, have you match xcode sdk version?

Comment: What about posting the source code where the error occurs?

Comment: @OJ Kwon: Yeah, the official instructions speaks from Xcode 9.4.1 and macOS sdk 10.13, both I tried now. Similar errors.

Comment: @trojanfoe I am sorry, but I can't do that.  I haven't changed the official code. So, it is original and not edited by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chromium seems to have updated its code for macOS 10.15.
You can find the updated code here.
https://github.com/chromium/chromium/commit/961e7821b9356445f48e5ce2c077c40c2c6b2309

Answer (score 2):

**SDK incompability**
Electron/Chromium wasn't compatible with MacOSX 10.15 SDK when you tried to build. The required version is 10.14 as pointed out by

```
$ gn args out/Testing --list --short|grep sdk
mac_sdk_min = "10.14"
```

opposing to [the docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20191119120956/https://electronjs.org/docs/development/build-instructions-macos). Download it from an older XCode version or unofficially from GitHub via

```
svn checkout https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/tree/master/MacOSX10.14.sdk
```

and set it active for ninja, e.g. by including the path in `src/electron/build/args/testing.gn` via `mac_sdk_path = "$path_to_sdk_folder"`.
I reverted my changes (see original post) and deleted `out/Testing`, throwing away all compilation results. There might be a less destructive way to reset/recompile only affected files. Then [regenerate the config](https://electronjs.org/docs/development/build-instructions-gn#building) via `gn gen` and restart compiling.

Unfortunately the error with v8_context_snapshot persists:

```
ACTION //tools/v8_context_snapshot:generate_v8_context_snapshot(//build/toolchain/mac:clang_x64)
FAILED: v8_context_snapshot.bin
python ../../build/gn_run_binary.py ./v8_context_snapshot_generator --output_file=v8_context_snapshot.bin
[1119/152748.970749:FATAL:protected_memory.h(218)] Check failed: SetMemoryReadWrite(&writers, &writers + 1).
0   v8_context_snapshot_generator       0x000000010eda4829 base::debug::CollectStackTrace(void**, unsigned long) + 9
1   v8_context_snapshot_generator       0x000000010ec88dd3 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace() + 19
2   v8_context_snapshot_generator       0x000000010ec9b869 logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage() + 233
3   v8_context_snapshot_generator       0x000000010f1337df base::AutoWritableMemory::AutoWritableMemory(void*, void*) + 239
4   v8_context_snapshot_generator       0x000000010f133421 MojoEmbedderSetSystemThunks(MojoSystemThunks const*) + 257
5   v8_context_snapshot_generator       0x000000010c135c16 main + 86
6   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff6a0ed3d5 start + 1

./v8_context_snapshot_generator failed with exit code -5
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

The other option is to wait until upstream fixes it, which is already happening as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58927874/11760058). Or implement the neccessary changes yourself with the first one following, but more are needed.

---

**Original post**

Chromium has a [MTLDeviceProxy](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.h) which

> wraps all calls to an MTLDevice [and] reports progress to the GPU watchdog.

Unfortunately it lacks properties required for the [MTLDevice protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevice)
that Clang [can't auto-synthesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784454/when-should-i-use-synthesize-explicitly).
So we synthesize them explicitly in [components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/components/viz/common/gpu/metal_api_proxy.mm):

```
@implementation MTLDeviceProxy
- (id)initWithDevice:(id<MTLDevice>)device {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    device_.reset(device, base::scoped_policy::RETAIN);
    libraryCache_ = std::make_unique<MTLLibraryCache>();
  }
  return self;
}

// add synthesized properties here
@synthesize hasUnifiedMemory;
@synthesize location;
@synthesize locationNumber;
@synthesize maxTransferRate;
@synthesize barycentricCoordsSupported;
@synthesize supportsShaderBarycentricCoordinates;
@synthesize peerGroupID;
@synthesize peerIndex;
@synthesize peerCount;
@synthesize counterSets;
```

Also three abstract methods are missing.
Insert these three wrappers before the end:

```
PROXY_METHOD1(BOOL, supportsFamily, MTLGPUFamily)
PROXY_METHOD2_SLOW(nullable id<MTLCounterSampleBuffer>,
                   newCounterSampleBufferWithDescriptor,
                   MTLCounterSampleBufferDescriptor*,
                   error,
                   NSError**)
PROXY_METHOD2_SLOW(void,
               sampleTimestamps,
               NSUInteger *,
               gpuTimestamp,
               NSUInteger *)

#endif
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

I wonder how those properties and methods could have been forgotten and why this issue surfaces right now.
Happy compiling!

Comment: so, thank you, but I thing the problem is bigger then I thought. I implemented the changes and now, it results in other errors, that some delegates are not implemented. Now in /components/storage_monitor/image_capture_device.mm. I don't know whether this are problems from electron, chromium or simple my machine/system

Comment: Hi @Christopher I have the same problem here when I try to build chromium version 76.0.3809.146. Did you manage to resolve this ?

Comment: @TonyG: no, I haven‘t found a solution. Maybe w e should open a bug report

Comment: @Christopher To which problem you facing right now ..I manage to solve many of them.

Comment: @TonyG: a problem with the v8_context_snapshot_generator. Something with protected_memory.h.

Comment: @TonyG
`[1/193] ACTION //tools/v8_context_snapshot:generate_v8_context_snapshot(//build/toolchain/mac:clang_x64)
FAILED: v8_context_snapshot.bin
python ../../build/gn_run_binary.py ./v8_context_snapshot_generator --output_file=v8_context_snapshot.bin
[1119/094505.100689:FATAL:protected_memory.h(218)] Check failed: SetMemoryReadWrite(&writers, &writers + 1).

[snipped stack trace]

./v8_context_snapshot_generator failed with exit code -5
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.`