# Extend UIView and add property in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, extend

I would like to add one property to UIView. 
I know I could subclass an UIView but as I want to add onelly one property I would like just to extend it.

I try like this :

```
@interface UIView (Util)
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL isShow;
@end

@implementation UIView (Util)
@dynamic isShow;

-(void)setIsShow:(BOOL)isShow{
    self.isShow = isShow;
}
@end
```

but it doesn't work. It throw an exception : `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2,address,...)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C: Property in Category](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733104/objective-c-property-in-category)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to add a new property in a category you'll have to use `objc_setAssociatedObject` and `objc_getAssociatedObject`.

Example:

```
NSString *const IS_SHOW_KEY = @"IS_SHOW";

@interface UIView (Util)
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isShow;
@end

@implementation UIView (Util)

- (void)setIsShow:(BOOL)isShow {
    NSNumber *val = @(isShow);
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, (__bridge const void*)(IS_SHOW_KEY), val, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (BOOL)isShow {
    NSNumber *val = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, (__bridge const void*)IS_SHOW_KEY);
    return [val boolValue];
}

@end
```

See the docs for the Runtime Reference here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Thank you. This is it. For all others you should include `#import <objc/runtime.h>`

Answer (score 0):

You should not add properties through category - you can only add methods. Read more here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html

You can however achieve what you need by creating methods for setting / getting values you need.

```
@interface UIView (Util)
-(void)setIsShow:(BOOL)isShow;
@end

@implementation UIView (Util)
@dynamic isShow;

-(void)setIsShow:(BOOL)isShow{
    self.isShow = isShow;
}
@end
```

If you really need properties, than you need to subclass