# how to define delegate method as property in class category?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

Good day!=)
I have "super" class and category for it)
For super class i defined a protocol delegate property but i can't call it in category in method. Is it possible anyway? Thanks everybody for answering=)

Comment: Can you provide a code example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Definitely need to see your code. You can't define a 'method' as a 'property' so your question title doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't get anything here im afraid. please try to reformulate, provide more details & code as well

Comment: Yes, my question is not right. It was simple mistake in my code and therefore couldn't subscribe for event of delegation( All in all Duncan is right=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your terms are all confused. A category is not a superclass or a subclass. A category adds methods to an existing class.

A method is not a property, so "defining a delegate method property" does not make sense.

You can't add new instance variables to an object in a category, so you can't add normal properties at all. You can create properties with custom getters/setters that don't use instance variables, or that use existing instance variables (for example if you had a "Person" class that had a "firstName" property and a "lastName" property you could create a new read-only property "fullName" that concatenated the first and last name and returned the result.)

Comment: I recommend to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14899909/3086454) answer for good example.

Comment: @RottenBrain, Given that the OP can't describe what he's trying to do in coherent sentences I think associative storage is a little beyond his current abilities. Cool technique, but not for newbies.

Comment: Maybe you're right. But this is really great technique for implementing "property" in category.

Comment: Yes, my question is not right. It was simple mistake in my code and therefore couldn't subscribe for event of delegation( All in all Duncan is right=)