# Using a data structure?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, data-structures, typedef

Currently I have a view `UIView *myView;`. I would like to add data to the view by saying something like `myView.stringdata = @"whatever";`. How can I do this?
Sorry for the simple question I'm new to Xcode.

Comment: Do you want to add a label to the view or actually store random data on the view?

Comment: I would like to attach a nsstring to the view. Not a visible object. @jervine10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add random data to views. You can subclass UIView if you want and add a property to the class and store your string there. Or you could make a property in the ViewController that is driving your UIVIew and assign the string to it.

Comment: this isnt necesarily true because he can make a category that holds a property and the works exactly as he was hoping

Comment: @ASKASK Incorrect. Categories **cannot** add instance variables or properties. This is what Apple says: `Categories can be used to declare either instance methods or class methods but are not usually suitable for declaring additional properties. It’s valid syntax to include a property declaration in a category interface, but it’s not possible to declare an additional instance variable in a category. This means the compiler won’t synthesize any instance variable, nor will it synthesize any property accessor methods.`

Comment: @ASKASK Workaround is using associative references. Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8733320/1407017

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add data to an instance of a class if the class does not have an ivar + accessor or a property for it.

You need to use one of the following approaches:

Subclass
Category
Delegate
Associative Objects
Composition
Collections

All of these involve modifying the class as a whole in your app (or any app if it were a framework class in a framework visible at the user or system level) or they involve creating new classes or association by being in collection member.