# set associated objects for literal value in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Well, this possibly a duplicated question. 
I've found some questions like this one:
[Is there a way to set associated objects in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133058/is-there-a-way-to-set-associated-objects-in-swift)

However, I want to add an `Int` property into swift's `extension` and these answers in the link above doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
import ObjectiveC
var xoAssociationKey: UInt8 = 0

extension NSData {

    var position: Int {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &xoAssociationKey) as Int
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &xoAssociationKey, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC))
        }
    }

    override convenience init() {
        self.init()
        position = 0
    }
}
```

And I get `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` everytime I access `position`

FYI, I did find a solution for this error in **Objective C** and I'm looking for a swift solution. Here's my code in objective C if you interested:

```
static char PROPERTY_KEY;

@implementation NSData (Extension)
@dynamic position;
- (NSInteger)position {
    return  [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &PROPERTY_KEY) integerValue];
}
- (void)setPosition:(NSInteger)position {
    // Must convert to an object for this trick to work
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &PROPERTY_KEY, @(position), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY);
}

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.position = 0;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSData` is part of a class cluster, so your custom init method is not necessarily called,
e.g.

```
let d = NSMutableData()
```

does not use your `init` method. The next problem is that your init method calls
itself recursively, therefore

```
let d = NSData()
```

crashes with a stack overflow. Note also that the Objective-C code relies on 
undefined behaviour, because it replaces a method in a class extension.

So better remove your custom initialization, and change the getter to 
return a default value if the associated object has not been set.
This can easily be achieved with an optional cast (`as? Int`) and the
nil-coalescing operator (`??`):

```
extension NSData {

    var position: Int {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &xoAssociationKey) as? Int ?? 0
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &xoAssociationKey, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC))
        }
    }
}
```