# Translating @interface UIView from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, uikit-dynamics

I'm following an Objective-C tutorial on how to animate a menu with UIKit Dynamics and I'm having some trouble translating the following code from Objective-C to Swift.

animator.h

```
@interface Animator : NSObject

+ (instancetype)animatorWithScreen:(UIScreen *)screen;

- (void)addAnimation:(id<Animation>)animatable;
- (void)removeAnimation:(id<Animation>)animatable;

@end

@interface UIView (AnimatorAdditions)

- (Animator *)animator;

@end
```

animator.m

```
@implementation Animator
{
}

+ (instancetype)animatorWithScreen:(UIScreen *)screen
{
    if (!screen) {      
        screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    }
    Animator *driver = objc_getAssociatedObject(screen, &ScreenAnimationDriverKey);
    if (!driver) {
        driver = [[self alloc] initWithScreen:screen];
        objc_setAssociatedObject(screen, &ScreenAnimationDriverKey, driver, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    }
    return driver;
}

@implementation UIView (AnimatorAdditions)

- (Animator *)animator
{
    return [Animator animatorWithScreen:self.window.screen];
}

@end
```

I was able to get everything else working, but I'm unsure how to get the UIView to have the animator property using Swift and also how to properly translate:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(screen, &ScreenAnimationDriverKey, driver, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

Comment: regarding objc_setAssociatedObject:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133058/is-there-a-way-to-set-associated-objects-in-swift - regarding the animator: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html

Comment: Awesome, I'm not sure why I'm getting so heavily downvoted since I just wanted some guidelines. If you could add that as an answer I'll set it as the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already an existing discussion about `objc_setAssociatedObject` for swift: ["Is there a way to set associated objects in Swift?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133058/is-there-a-way-to-set-associated-objects-in-swift).

What you are trying to do with the `Animator` is called an **extension**. That of course is available for swift as well - take a look at [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html) for how to create one yourself.