# Objective C & Swift Interoperability causes error "Extensions may not contain stored properties"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iboutlet, language-interoperability

I was working on one of my previous app that was done on Objective C. I need to add a new module to it and I decided to use Swift for that particular module.

I have a class called `HomePage` in Objective C, I wanted to add some new `IBAction`s and `IBOutlet`s in it. For that I added a new swift file and extended the existing class like:

```
// MARK: IBOutlets and IBActions
extension HomePage
{
    @IBOutlet var image : UIImageView!
    ...

    /*!
    * Loads the application support webpage
    */
    @IBAction func loadSupportURL(sender : UIButton)
    {
    }
    ...
}
```

If I add only the IBActions everything is working perfectly. But when I add an IBOutlet, the compiler throws an error like:

> Extensions may not contain stored properties

For fixing it I have two ways,

1. Declare the outlet in my Objective C class itself
2. Convert the whole Objective C class to Swift and declare the property there

Is there any other way to fix this issue ?

Comment: @IBOutlet var image : UIImageView! is this right?

Comment: @IBOutlet var image : UIImageView()

Comment: Yeah, as the compiler says, you cannot have stored properties in an extension, so you'd have to go with one of your solutions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error message clearly states, you can't have stored properties in an extension. But the thing is, you can't have them in Objective-C categories either, so the language isn't the problem here.

In both languages, you need to use associated references to implement stored properties. Please see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133058/is-there-a-way-to-set-associated-objects-in-swift) for an example of using associated references in Swift. Since it is a C API, its usage is pretty much the same in Objective-C.