# How to create a static pointer variable to itself in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, pointers

In Objective-C I often use the pattern of using a `static void*` as an identification tag. At times these tags are only used within that function/method, hence it's convenient to place the variable inside the function.

For example:

```
MyObscureObject* GetSomeObscureProperty(id obj) {
    static void* const ObscurePropertyTag = &ObscurePropertyTag;
    MyObscureObject* propValue = objc_getAssociatedObject(id,ObscurePropertyTag);
    if(!propValue) {
        propValue = ... // lazy-instantiate property
        objc_setAssociatedObject(obj,ObscurePropertyTag,propValue, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
    }
    return propValue; 
}
```

The question is, how to write the `ObscurePropertyTag` private-constant-pointer-to-itself in Swift? (Preferrably 2.1 but future already-announced versions should be okay)

I've looked around and it seems that I have to put this `ObscurePropertyTag` as a member variable and there doesn't seem to be a way around it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve. Converting your Objective-C code to the Swift equivalent may not be the best option.

Comment: @Michael One example is to associate `MKPolyline` objects shown within a map view with their underlying data model objects. Another is for identifying particular subsets of `CALayer` objects (without creating yet another collection object to contain them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike (Objective-)C, you cannot take the address of an 
uninitialized variable in Swift. Therefore creating a self-referencing
pointer is a two-step process:

**Swift 2:**

```
var ptr : UnsafePointer<Void> = nil
withUnsafeMutablePointer(&ptr) { $0.memory = UnsafePointer($0) }
```

**Swift 3:**

```
var ptr = UnsafeRawPointer(bitPattern: 1)!
ptr = withUnsafePointer(to: &ptr) { UnsafeRawPointer($0) }
```

For your purpose, is it easier to use the address of a *global* variable with `&`, see for 
example

- [Is there a way to set associated objects in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133058/is-there-a-way-to-set-associated-objects-in-swift/25428409#25428409).

If you want to restrict the scope of the "tag" to the function itself
then you can use a *static* variable inside a local `struct`. Example:

```
func obscureProperty(obj : AnyObject) -> MyObscureObject {
    struct Tag {
        static var ObscurePropertyTag : Int = 0
    } 
    if let propValue = objc_getAssociatedObject(obj, &Tag.ObscurePropertyTag) as? MyObscureObject {
        return propValue
    }
    let propValue = ... // lazy instantiate property value
    objc_setAssociatedObject(obj, &Tag.ObscurePropertyTag,propValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
    return propValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var GetSomeObscureProperty: MyObscureObject = nil

withUnsafePointer(& GetSomeObscureProperty) {
    GetSomeObscureProperty = MyObscureObject($0) 
}
```

In short

```
let GetSomeObscureProperty = UnsafePointer<()>()
```

Comment: Please try and let me know.