# Object wrapper (surrogate) forwarding methods in Swift

Tags: swift, wrapper

`CBPeripheral` is a painful object to test as it can not be instanced by itself. Therefore, I'm using a wrapper (`HBRPeripheralWrapper`) around it (also for other purposes).

I would like to forward most of call on the wrapper 
(`HBRPeripheralWrapper`) to the actual wrapped object `CBPeripheral`.

It technically works using `forwardInvocation` but how can I adopt a similar pattern in `Swift`?

PS: `NSInvocation` is not available in `Swift`

```
class HBRPeripheralWrapper {
  let peripheral:CBPeripheral

  // I would like to avoid this "manual" forwarding
  var identifier: NSUUID {
      get {
          return peripheral.identifier
      }
  }

  init(peripheral:CBPeripheral) {
    self.peripheral = peripheral
  }

  // target forwarding is great, but how can I make the compiler happy?
  override func forwardingTargetForSelector(aSelector: Selector) -> AnyObject? {
    if(self.peripheral.respondsToSelector(aSelector)) {
      return self.peripheral
    }
    return super.forwardingTargetForSelector(aSelector)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making `HBRPeripheralWrapper`, consider extending `CBPeripheral`

```
extension CBPeripheral {
    // add whatever else you need here.
}
```

You don't say exactly what you do in `HBRPeripheralWrapper` other than forwarding, so I can't provide more help.

Comment: Thx for answer. I'm wrapping rather than sub classing because I'm adding some functionality that don't make sense as subclass and also because you can't create manually `CBPeripheral` on iOS. Beside this consideration any idea how to make a nice wrapper?

Comment: I'm not suggesting you subclass.  Extension methods are added to any objects of the class -- even ones you don't create.  Add more info about exactly what you are trying to do, and I'll add more to this answer.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry. But I need storage.

Comment: You can use associated objects for storage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133058/is-there-a-way-to-set-associated-objects-in-swift

Comment: Thx. I know about this. I would like to try a more composed solution.

Comment: Also, (last but not least), I'm storing optional closure on the object, so optional closure storage on swift is pretty hardcore looking..