# How to extend UITextView class?

Tags: ios, oop, swift3, uitextview

All I need to add an extra variable to `UITextView` class .

**My First Attempt :**

```
extension UITextView
{
   var id : String
}
```

But it gives an error message `Extension may not contain stored properties`!

**Second Attempt :**

```
extension UITextView
{
   var id : String
   {
    get { return self.id }
    set(newValue) { self.id = newValue }
   }
}
```

But it crushes my app and give an error message `Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when I attempt to assign a value in `var id` .

[image]

How can I assign value in `var id` and print it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **Associated Objects** I solved my problems .

Here is my source code (**Swift3**) . .

```
import ObjectiveC

var AssociatedObjectHandle: UInt8 = 0

extension UITextView
{
   var id : String
   {
        get
        {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedObjectHandle) as! String
        }
        set
        {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedObjectHandle, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }

   }
}
```

Thanks **mag_zbc** and **rmaddy** for your useful answers !

Answer (score 2):

> All I need to add an extra variable to UITextView class

You can't add stored properties in extension. The only way is to use computed properties and associated objects, but that's ugly. You should rather write a class that inherits UITextView.

If you **really** can't subclass UITextView, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133058/is-there-a-way-to-set-associated-objects-in-swift) answer how to use associated objects with computed properties.

Comment: I tried  so called `ugly` way but it says `Use of unresolved  identifier OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC ` , what is wrong here ?

Comment: @Roy Look [at the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40862150/1226963) for Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that, Because properties need storage and adding properties would change the memory structure of the class as well as introduce a whole host of other issues in usability.

Extensions are meant to augment behaviours, not fundamentally change a class. So, If you need to add additional properties to a class you can do that using Subclass that uses Parent class as `UITextView`