# Extending a method applicable to all UIButtons

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uibutton

I have a UIButton object in my program.
I want to use it like follows

```
myButton.setImage:blablabla
mybutton.title:.......blabla
...
...
myButton.placeTextBelowImageWithSpacing:12
```

While calling my method "placeTextBelowImageWithSpacing:12" it must set the image and text accordingly. I have the method ready with me. How can i use it in the above way.

PS: I hate subclassing.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is that really Objective-C? Else, try `Category`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom subclass of UIButton. I created a button called FinderButton that has an image and a title centered below it. It works great.

If you hate subclassing then you might want to think about a different line of work.

Being an Objective C programmer that hates subclassing is a bit like being a surgeon who hates blood or a farmer who hates dirt. Defining a class hierarchy is one of the main tools for doing development in an OO language like Objective-C.

Comment: **Being an Objective C programmer that hates subclassing is a bit like being a surgeon who hates blood** - Wow

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a UIButton category:

**UIButton+MyCustomMethod.h**

```
@interface UIButton (MyCustomMethod)

- (void)placeTextBelowImageWithSpacing;

@end
```

**UIButton+MyCustomMethod.m**

```
@implementation UIButton (MyCustomMethod)

- (void)placeTextBelowImageWithSpacing
{
    // ...
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That isn't valid syntax in Objective-C. The closest you can get to that would be to explicitly declare new properties on UIButton that followed your naming convention. Using them would then look like:

```
myButton.setTitle = @"something"
```

Then you could override setTitle's setter (`setSetTitle:`), and making it call `setTitle:forControlState:`, which I'm assuming is your goal.

But this *should* only be done through subclassing (learn to love it, it's a big part of OOP), although if you really really want to, you can add the properties in a category using the Objective-C runtime `objc_setAssociatedObject()` function more info here: [Objective-C: Property / instance variable in category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733104/objective-c-property-instance-variable-in-category)