# Create a delegate in a Category

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, objective-c-category

Is it possible to create a delegate in a Category?

Let's say, i have a Category `UIImageView (ImagePicker)`, in which i've create some methods and all work perfectly.

However, i need to add a delegate into this category, `UIImageViewDelegate` let's say. Because at some point in the `UIImageView (ImagePicker)` implementation, i need it to trigger a event, and i want the user to catch this event.

Since i'm creating a category, and properties are not allowed in the category. So it seems that there is no way for me to add such a delegate, because based on my knowledge, to have create a delegate, you always have to create a property in the interface like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <UIImageViewDelegate> delegate;
```

Does anyone have any idea on this?

**EDIT:**

The logic of this Category,

The function of this category is to enable the user to set the UIImage of the UIImageView, by choose a photo from the Photo.app. The category handles all the process including the UI interactions. Now i need a delegate to call back to user when the image is set.

Comment: Your question boils down to "how to create a property in a category." You need to use an associated object. See the answer to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733104/objective-c-property-instance-variable-in-category

Comment: Also consider wether a category or a wrapper object is a better implementation for your situation.

Comment: At this point you should consider creating a proper subclass of `UIImageView`. It's hard to know for sure since there aren't enough details about what you are doing. A category should only be used to add a new method or two. When you get to the point where you really have a specialized `UIImageView`, you need a subclass.

Comment: (Btw. you can define *properties* in a category if they are not backed up by an *instance variable*. So this does not help here :)

Comment: @rmaddy the function of this category is to enable the user to set the UIImage of the UIImageView, by choose a photo from the Photo.app. The category handles all the process including the UI interactions. Now i need a delegate to call back to user when the image is set.

Comment: @triplegg Right. So at this point you have a specialized `UIImageView`. That's a good indication you should subclass `UIImageView` and put all of your additions and delegate in the subclass. Then use the subclass throughout your app where this is needed.

Comment: @triplegg I would also argue that you should not subclass `UIImageView`. Instead, create some sort of controller class. The controller class can be setup with a reference to a `UIImageView`. Then the controller does all of the communication between the image picker and the image view.

Comment: @rmaddy right, but it could be much cooler if it can be done by just a category. because the rest functions work perfectly except for the delegate

Comment: You don't have to have a `delegate` property to create or use a delegate.  You do need some way for the object that is going to invoke the delegate to actually find the delegate, and a property is the most convenient way to do this.

Comment: @HotLicks how can i create a delegate without having to declare a property ?

Comment: @triplegg - Well, you can *create* a delegate that doesn't store anything -- it might just be "pure procedure" methods that return a value based only on the inputs.  And to *use* a delegate you simply need a place to store the delegate pointer, and that can be a simple instance variable -- does not need to be a property.