# Properties defined in category not found in original class

Tags: objective-c, compiler-warnings, objective-c-category, declared-property

I have a very large class that I am trying to create a category from.  In the original class' .m file, I have 2 objects (defined in the category .h file) that I'm getting "unidentified identifier" build errors.

This is the object definition of one of them in the UploadViewController+CreateExportFiles.h class:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *booksArray;
```

The .h file of the original class (UploadViewController.h) looks like this:

```
#import "UploadViewController.h"
#import "UploadViewController+CreateExportFiles.h"
```

and the usage of `booksArray` in the class where I'm getting the error is:

```
if( [[[booksArray objectAtIndex:i] tranCode] isEqualToString:@"A"])
```

Is there something else I have to do to resolve the error?

Comment: Part of your problem could be that `objectAtIndex` returns `id` and the parser does not recognise `tranCode` ?

Comment: No, because before I split this class (original was too large to manage) all of the code worked without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Categories can't add storage to classes. By moving the property declaration to a category from the main class interface, you've stopped the compiler from creating the ivar `booksArray` for you, which is the entity that you're referring to with `[booksArray objectAtIndex:i]`.

You need to put the property back into the main class interface or a class extension, or [use a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733104/objective-c-property-instance-variable-in-category?lq=1).

Comment: Hi Josh... that took care of the problem; how would I call the class that is now in the category class?  I have another class that instantiated the original class and called that method; it, of course, is not found anymore... i.e.     UploadViewController *uvc = [[UploadViewController alloc]init];
    [uvc createTabExportFile: @"Backup"];

Comment: The category header needs to be imported wherever you want to call the methods that are defined in the category, which includes properties.

Comment: Ahhh Crap!  I knew that... just forgot it... thanks again for your help; I appreciate it... have a good evening.  SD

Comment: Sorry Josh... still not working... same exact problem even after I did what you suggested... except now it's "undeclared identifiers" in the category class for the same two objects... I've tried everything I could think of to no avail...