# Connecting next field chain for form text fields

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder

I'm trying to connect the text fields in a sign up form so that, upon done being pressed for each, the next field in the form automatically becomes active. To achieve this, I've extended the UITextField class, as follows, in the view controller for the sign up view.

```
@interface UITextField (Extended)
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField* nextField;
@end
```

I've then set the nextField outlets via interface builder for each field in the form, and have the following code implemented in the view controller, which is also acting as the delegate for the text fields in the form.

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    UITextField* field = textField.nextField;
    if (field)
        [field becomeFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

However when building and running the app, it immediately crashes giving the following error :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', 
reason:'[<UITextField 0x78729580> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nextField.'
```

A bit lost as to how to address this, any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove all the outlets and recreate them again. You just missed or duplicated one of them, since you have several textfields it is highly possible something has gone awry. And make sure that each nextField really points to next field :)

UPDATE: It's late night so I missed one big problem.
You can't add new properties via category to an existing class like that. The reason is category is not capable of creating a backing variable behind the scenes. (There is a way with associated objects..but it's best not to delve into that black magic.)

Instead of `UItextField+extended` category, **subclass** the `UITextfield` class.

```
@interface CustomTextField : UITextField

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *nextField;

@end
```

Then in interface builder, you will have to set that CustomTextfield class in the class inspector for each text field.

Comment: I've tried removing and reconnecting the outlets multiple times, and the issue persists. Do all outlets have to be connected to something? Will an unconnected outlet cause a problem?

Comment: Check the Update: in this answer.

Comment: This did it! Allowed them to be set via IB, worked like a charm. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that while you can **declare** a property in a category, the compiler will not **define** the property getter and setter for you. You have to define the getter and setter yourself.

You can use an “associated object” to store the property value.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14899909/77567) for example code. Since you don't want your `nextField` property to retain the next field, use `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN` instead of `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC` when setting the associated object.