# NSURL+Category with NSURLSessionDownloadTask

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurl, objective-c-category

I have a category for my `NSURL` to set my `DataModel` for accessing my model objects later. Here, my `DataModel` is subclassed of my Core Data entity `(NSManagedObject)`

---

```
@implementation NSURL (CustomizedObject)

static char PROPERTY_KEY;

@dynamic model;

- (void)setChunk:(DataModel *)model {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &PROPERTY_KEY, model, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (DataModel *)model {
    return (DataModel *)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &PROPERTY_KEY);
}

@end
```

---

So, i'm downloading my data through `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`

---

```
for (DataModel *model in models) { // Here 985 URLs are there
    if ([model.status integerValue] == 0) {
        NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:model.downloadSequence];
        [requestURL setModel:model];
        NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [self.session downloadTaskWithURL:requestURL];
        [downloadTask resume];

        [self.arrFileDownloadData addObject:downloadTask];
    }
}
```

---

And, i'm accessing my `DataModel` in every successful download,

---

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
{
    self.downloadSuccessCount++;

    DownloadModel *model = downloadTask.originalRequest.URL.model;
    NSString *filePath = [model.content.filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[model.streamingSequence lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension]];

    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSURL *destinationURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[destinationURL path]]) {
        [fileManager removeItemAtURL:destinationURL error:nil];
    }

    BOOL success = [fileManager copyItemAtURL:location toURL:destinationURL error:&error];

    if (success) {
        NSError *fetchError = nil;

        NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:ChunkCoreData];
        [fetch setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"modelId == %@", model.modelId]];

        NSArray *isProductExist = [self.context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&fetchError];

        if ([isProductExist count] != 0) {
            DataModel *fetchedModel = [isProductExist lastObject];
            fetchedModel.status = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];

            // create writer MOC
            NSManagedObjectContext* _privateWriterContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
            [_privateWriterContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[[self managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator]];

            // create main thread MOC
            NSManagedObjectContext* _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
            _managedObjectContext.parentContext = _privateWriterContext;

            NSError *saveError = nil;
            if (![_privateWriterContext save:&saveError]) {
                NSLog(@"Couldn't save %@", saveError.localizedDescription);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Everything, works fine except sometimes. I'm getting crash in,

```
NSURL *destinationURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
```

to says that **`filePath`** is nil. Or the issue is with my `NSURL` category creation?

What i'm doing here wrong? Suggestions please.

Comment: How does the combination of `char` and `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC` work?

Comment: @Droppy Then, what else i've to give to access my `DataModel` to access through `NSURL` i'm very new to *Categories*

Comment: Yeah my mistake; looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8733320/3588973) answer, that *is* how it's done with categories.  I rarely use them as they just complicate things and I like *simple*.

Comment: Why not check if `filePath` exists before setting `destinationURL`?

Comment: @l'L'l You mean, checking `filePath` as `nil` or with `NSFileManager`

Comment: I think you could do it either way (NSFileManager or filePath == nil) — NSFileManager would be the more preferable way I'd imagine. If it doesn't exist or is nil then return an error message perhaps. Do you have any idea of why it's returning nil? If not maybe `NSLog` `model.content.filePath`, or `model.streamingSequence`, it might give you some better idea of what is happening...

Comment: So, does my `NSURL` category is perfect. Or i've to create it in separate class with static key value like in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14899909/940096)

Comment: Well the question is, why does filePath return nil in the first place?

Comment: Yeah. But, i'm very new to adding properties into `Categories` That's why i'm asking? :) Even, i've updated the question

Comment: Maybe try putting `if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[filePath path]]) {
        [fileManager removeItemAtURL:filePath error:nil];
    }` before `NSURL *destinationURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];` and see what it does...

Comment: may be there is space in "filePath". so it could not convert to Url and and it gets crash.

Answer (score 0):

I know that **NSURLSession** does *not* handle subclasses of **NSURLRequest**; it was a disaster in iOS 7, borderline unusable in iOS 8, and still pretty buggy in iOS 9.

I think this is because the objects are serialized to a plist even when the requests are handled in-process.  I suspect that you're hitting the same bugs that I did, in which case associated objects on **NSURLRequest** or **NSURL** are likely to be equally problematic.

As an alternative, here are some other techniques that might work better for you:

- Use `setProperty:forKey:inRequest:` and `property:forKey:inRequest:` on the **NSURLRequest** object instead.
- For non-background sessions, add associated objects to the task instead.
- Create a dictionary that maps the URL request object to the data you want.

HTH.