# JSQMessagesViewController How to set link to image bubble?

Tags: objective-c, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I would like to set link to image bubble.
When the image bubble is tapped, I would like to show the linked web site.
Is it possible?
If yes, how to do it or what is the easiest way?
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Just add a `UITapGesture` on the image bubble. Once someone taps on the imageBubble you get a callback, use this to navigate to required website. https://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I see. That is the way. How should I distinguish among some image bubbles, which is which link? Can I use "tag" like UIButton?

Comment: I would prefer using a UIImage Category and add a property like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733104/objective-c-property-instance-variable-in-category and then get the value from that.

Comment: Thank you for your additional information, but ... I need to learn more about UIImage Category. Thanks anyway.