# Add a property to all view controllers in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

View controllers in my iPhone app either extend from `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`. I need to add a property to all of them so that I can pass user information between controllers. The solution I am aware of is to add a `BaseViewController` and a `BaseTableViewController`, add the property to both of them, then make all controllers to inherit from them instead.

Repeating the property in `BaseViewController` and `BaseTableViewController` doesn't seem to be the most elegant solution to me. Is there any better ones?

Thanks!

Comment: Here the explanations [bjective-C categories: Can I add a property for a method not in my category?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520889/objective-c-categories-can-i-add-a-property-for-a-method-not-in-my-category

Answer (score 0):

As extensions will not work in your case, you could write a category on UIViewController and use `objc_getAssociatedObject` to store the data you want and retrieve it with `objc_getAssociatedObject`. But you should use this option with care.

```
static NSString *key = @"example";

- (void)setExampleProperty:(id)value {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, (__bridge void *)key, value, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}

- (id)exampleProperty {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, (__bridge void *)key);
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Sweet! That's what I want. Thanks!