# Objective C best way to see how many times a method is called

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I want to determine how many times a particular method is called on NSManagedObject.

What are anybody's suggestions for the best way of doing this?

Bearing in mind that i have 30+ managed objects and I don't want to change the superclass of all of them.

Thanks

Comment: You tried good ol' NSLog where you fire the method?

Comment: Its in far too many places, and the method is in Cocoa libraries. I want an easyish way to do it. But there will be an NSLog involved at some point.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void) method {

   static int callCount = 0;
   callCount++;

   /* method body */

}
```

Comment: The method i want to track is in Cocoa library - but what you have written it what I would use normally. Thanks

Comment: @bandejapaisa perhaps you could get some kind of answer out of instruments?

Answer (score 1):

Create an alternate method in a category that tracks the number of calls in a static variable and the swizzle the method with the original implementation. See http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MethodSwizzling for a code sample.

Comment: This swizzle code doesn't want to compile with Xcode 4.2 on LLVM 3 against iOS 5..... this was the way I thought of doing it originally, but thought there might be another way that I've forgotten about... any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you try this method? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637604/method-swizzle-on-iphone-device/1638940#1638940

Comment: You shouldn't use method swizzling tho.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339276/what-are-the-dangers-of-method-swizzling-in-objective-c

Comment: Yeah, this is solely for debugging and performance improvements. I'm not putting this code into production with method swizzles.