# Where to put common code for optional protocol method implementation?

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns

I have a protocol P

```
@protocol P<NSObject>
{

-(void)foo;

@optional

-(void)bar;

}
```

And I have bunch of classes (let say a dozen). All of these classes implement protocol P. About half of them implement method **bar** and all of bar implementations are exactly the same.

What is the best way to share implementation of **bar**?

**Obvious ideas:**

1) Create some base class which will implement method bar and let other classes to inherit it.

It's simple to implement. However, I am not big fan of this idea. I prefer class hierarchy to represent entity generalization/specification rather than code reuse.

2) Create a helper and call it from all of classes which needs to implement bar method

Ok. It works. However, if implementation of bar is small (couple of lines in my case) then we will have more overhead (helper class and calling it from each class) than the code itself.

Is there any other (better) methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few ways to share method implementations between classes:

1. Inheritance.  You can make all your classes inherit from a common base class that implements the shared methods.  But you can't do this if, for example, you need class A to inherit from `UIViewController` and class B to inherit from `NSManagedObject`.
2. Create a category on a base class shared by all your classes.  For example, `NSObject` is the base class of (virtually) every other class.  You can create a category on `NSObject` to add methods that all classes inherit.  If you do this, you should put a prefix your method names to ensure that they won't conflict with other names.  E.g. use `ronin_foo` and `ronin_bar` instead of just `foo` and `bar`.
3. Create a file containing the method implementations, **not** surrounded by an `@implementation` block.  Then `#include` this file in the middle of the `@implementation` block of each class that needs the methods.  Note that the compiler will generate a copy of the machine code for each class, so this could make your program substantially bigger.
4. At runtime, use the Objective-C runtime API to copy methods from one class to another.  You will need to read the [*Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and parts of the [*Objective-C Runtime Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418).  You will probably also need to google up some examples.

Comment: +1 #4 is a great answer, tricky though. I almost got it on my own, but ended up borrowing the `method_getImplementation()` from Larson's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1638940/1218605 to actually transfer the guts of the method. This is me getting it to work, with files listed in a gist: https://gist.github.com/C4Framework/7228100