# Declare conditional delegate methods in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I am looking for a way to declare the implementation of delegate methods to be conditionally linked to each other. I am aware of the way of `@required` and `@optional` for mark specific methods. But I'd like to have a way to mark a method as required, if another is implemented. Is this possible?

What I like to do is something like this:

Think of the following delegate methods:

```
- (void) firstSuccessDelegateMethod;
- (void) firstErrorDelegateMethod;
- (void) secondSuccessDelegateMethod;
- (void) secondErrorDelegateMethod;
```

Is there a way to declare something like

if `firstSuccessDelegateMethod` is implemented, `firstErrorDelegateMethod` is required
if `secondSuccessDelegateMethod` is implemented, `secondErrorDelegateMethod` is required

Thanks!

Comment: No this isn't possible.  You can document the conditions you want and enforce it at runtime by checking the right combinations of implemented methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly this isn't possible, though you could always coalesce the two delegate methods into one, e.g.,

```
- (void)delegateMethodWithResult:(id)result error:(NSError *)error
```

Answer (score 0):

That is impossible requiring delegates in runtime, but it is possible to dynamically add/implement method in runtime.. [check that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818980/dynamically-implementing-a-delegate-during-runtime)

So, the only possible option is to require `firstSuccessDelegateMethod` and add `firstErrorDelegateMethod` to the target class when triggered, but the easiest way is to combine the two like what @johnpatrickmorgan said.