# Objective-C override valueForKey: of NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, overriding, nsmutabledictionary

I need to override the valueForKey: method of a NSMutableDictionary. I want to check for a specific value, do some manipulation and return it. Are there any points that should I be aware of ? Please correct me if there is something wrong, for example:

```
- (id)valueForKey:(NSString*)key {

    id val = [super valueForKey:key];
    if([val isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [val isEqualToString:@"<null>"]) {
        return @"No Value";
    }
    else {
        return val;
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: use Categories the proper way to do this http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/learn-objective-c-day-6/

Comment: @moon: the problem with categories is that you can't cleanly call the original implementation of anything you replace; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085479/override-a-method-via-objc-category-and-call-the-default-implementation

Comment: This sounds like a job for a data transformer, actually.

Comment: xm indeed, but I also use them with IB bindings, TableViews, etc and sounds that I'd have more code to replace this way

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably don't want to override `valueForKey`, because `NSDictionary` and `NSMutableDictionary` are abstract base classes hiding a class cluster behind them. Per their documentation, in a straight subclassing you'd need to reimplement all of:

- setObject:forKey:
- removeObjectForKey:
- count
- objectForKey:
- keyEnumerator

It's easier to implement an alternative class that pretends to be an NSMutableDictionary but forwards any calls it doesn't understand to an actual NSMutableDictionary. Which you can do via [forwardingTargetForSelector:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/forwardingTargetForSelector%3a).

E.g.

```
@interface MyFakeDictionary: NSObject
{
    NSMutableDictionary *theRealDictionary;
}

/* reimplement whatever init methods you want to use */

- (id)valueForKey:(id)key;

@end

...

@implementation MyFakeDictionary

- (id)valueForKey:(id)key
{
   id val = [theRealDictionary objectForKey:key];
   /* etc, as you like */
}

- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
    return theRealDictionary;
}

@end
```

So there's no inheritance relationship between MyFakeDictionary and NSMutableDictionary, but if you send a selector to MyFakeDictionary that it doesn't understand (like any of the normal dictionary messages other than the one you've replaced), NSObject's built-in logic will redirect them to the member theRealDictionary. It's 'has a' rather than 'is a', with transparent message forwarding, and therefore conveniently dodges any issues with class clusters.

Comment: Of course I need to alloc it and release it in -init & -dealloc yeh? Sounds the best solution! But I've always be using @interface ... to declare classes, etc. The @class... make the compiler give me `... error: expected ';' before '{' token` ?? What am I missing ?

Comment: You're not missing anything, my brain was awry. You use @class for declaring that interfaces exist but not defining them, @interface for defining them. You're quite right to use @interface, I'm quite wrong to have used @class in my initial answer and I'll correct it immediately. And: yes, you'd need to create an NSMutableDictionary for the variable 'theRealDictionary' to reference in an init, release it in a dealloc. You'd actually need to reimplement the inits that you want so it you wanted 'initWithObjectsAndKeys:' you'd have to create the dictionary and then push the objects into it.

Comment: Thanks @Tommy, I' ll get back if the hall thing worked for my case.

Comment: xm, I' ll have to spend some time on this one, I take many warnings, errors like  ... `does not implement methodSignatureForSelector:`, etc issues. Still seems the right solution though... . Maybe I'll try a solution with NSValueTransformer witch might be best in my case. Thank you...

Comment: Sorry; just another error from coding extemporaneously: your object should inherit from NSObject. I'll correct my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must pay attention when subclassing NSMutableDictionary:

from the Apple docs:

```
Methods to Override

In a subclass, you must override both
of its primitive methods:

setObject:forKey: 
removeObjectForKey:
You must also override the primitive methods of the NSDictionary class.
```

Answer (score 0):

Take your code and wrap it in the following:

```
@implementation NSMutableDictionary(myValueForKey)

<your code here>

@end
```

This is a category on NSMutableDictionary. Categories make it easy to add to or augment standard methods without having to subclass.

One recommendation would be to use a different method name, though, since you won't want to call `[super valueForKey:...]` -- you'll want to call `[self valueForKey:...]`. So using a different method name for your method will differentiate yours from the standard method.

Comment: I use IB bindings, so I want valueForKey: to be "overridden", to be functional with bindings too. So do I call [super ...] for default implementation or [self ...] in case of category ? Thank you

Comment: With a category, you are extending a class, so when category method are called, `self` refers to the object (the receiver) on which the method is being called. So if you create a category method, say `myValueForKey:`, in that method `self` refers to the object on which you called `myValueForKey:`, and you can then call `[self valueForKey:...]` to get at the orginal class's `valueForKey:` method. This is different from subclassing a class and overriding a base class method. In this case, you would access the base class functionality by calling the original method on `super`.