# How can i use [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary] if the dictionary is empty?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

I get some data from the server and save it to `NSDictionary`  then I want to initialise `NSMutableDictionary` with that `NSDictionary`.

```
NSDictionary  * const received = [self serverData];
NSMutableDictionary * const results = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:received];
```

And If I get empty JSON from the server and consequently my `NSDictionary` will be empty how can I use `dictionaryWithDictionary` for an empty one? I use this

```
NSDictionary * const received = [self serverData];
NSMutableDictionary * const results;
if (![received count]) {
    results = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
}
else
{
    results = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:received];
}
```

But it seems a code smell. May be there are more elegant solutions?

Comment: do you get a nsdictionary object with no key-vale pair or nil?

Comment: I think that the problem is that when there is no data your dictionary is `nil` and you can't initialize a `NSMutableDictionary` from a `nil` object

Comment: If you use dictionarywithDictionary: and pass in nil or an empty dictionary, you get an empty dictionary. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: if you recieve nil then you don't need to use dictionarywithdictionary. you just need to do results = [recieved mutablecopy]; if nil then it'll be ignored

Comment: @Joe Why do you need to check if received is nil, won't it return you a dictionary either way?

Comment: Your right I assumed it was crashing.

Comment: That's what I'm not getting, surely `NSMutableDictionary* results = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:received];` is all that's needed. Unless i'm missing something.

Comment: @AbidHussain Can you please explain me a difference between these two states "object with no key-vale pair or nil"?

Comment: @JamesP Yes serverdata returns NSDictionary but further I need to use NSMutableDictionary

Comment: It will create you an empty NSMutableDictionary with which you can do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a category on `NSDictionary` that provides for such a safe setting.

```
+ (NSMutableDictionary *)safeDictionaryWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    return [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:(dictionary ? dictionary : @{});
}
```

Comment: What about overriding the existing method with category?

Comment: Categories do not have the ability to be polymorphed.  If polymorphism is your desire create a new class with this as a function.

Comment: It can be, but has some limitations... :)

Comment: Could you elaborate, I'm interested.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085479/override-a-method-via-objc-category-and-call-the-default-implementation

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I love runtime magic, I'm sure it will be a fun read.

Comment: There is no point in doing this, just calling dictionaryWithDictionary will give you the same result.

Answer (score 5):

You were fine in the first place.

```
NSDictionary* received = [self serverData];
NSMutableDictionary* results = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:received];
```

Will do what you want. Even if `received` is nil or empty, `results` will just be an empty NSMutableDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You cant create an item in dictionary with "no key". As key must be a non-nil string.

If no items are there then no object and no key are set, this leads to `setObject:nil forKey:nil`