# iOS. Add the same second action for UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath event?

Tags: ios, uitableview, methods, multiple-tables, didselectrowatindexpath

I have several UITableViews with ready delegate and dataSource methods. How to add the same second action/handler for these tables using subclassing but without of editing their didSelectRowAtIndexPath methods manually?

If I use UIButtons instead of tables then the solution is:

inside the child class of UIButton:

```
- (void)defaultInit {

    [self addTarget:[PCFlurryManager manager] action:@selector(...) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)dealloc {

    [self removeTarget:[PCFlurryManager manager] action:@selector(...) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

So I can use addTarget for the same event as much times as I want. But how to realize the similar for a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign `Tag` to your `UITableView`(s). And then you can access table via its tag.

Something like..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSLog(@"Tag: %d",tableView.tag);
    switch (tableView.tag) {
        case 1:
            //stuff for table 1
        break;

        case 2:
            //stuff for table 2
        break;

        default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: it is better than the previous answer but by using this way you still need to edit this method manually

Comment: @user2412679 what do you mean by **"you still need to edit this method manually"** ?

Comment: As I wrote I have several tables and each of them with its own didSelectRowAtIndexPath. So I need to remove them and copy-paste these instances of this method to another one class. For example when I use button I don't need to change/copy its own method for "touch up inside" event, because I can change its class only. So I can write a new code separately, without doubling and even without reassigning of delegate

Comment: @user2412679 You can create category over UITableView for this purpose.

Comment: thanks I will vote up you. But I think I have found a better solution

Comment: Please share your link for solution if you have and if you don't mind

Comment: I think I could create a category with this method and call the original method from it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085479/override-a-method-via-objc-category-and-call-the-default-implementation

Answer (score 0):

didSelectRowAtIndexPath give you a object (UITableView *)tableView that indicate this method is call for which tableview.

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
         if(tableView==YourFirstTableviewObject) {
                   //write your code for first
         } 
         else if(tableView==YourSecondTableviewObject) {
                   //write your code for second
         }   
         else if(tableView==YourThirdTableviewObject) {
                   //write your code for Third
         }
         ..........
    }
```

Comment: 1)in this answer you edit this method; 2)it causes a lot of code if the objects of these tables are in various classes